# How to make table border be behind background linear/radial gradient (scroll shadow)

Tags: html, css

I have created a table with horizontal scroll and a scroll shadow using the css below. What I am trying to do next is to hide the border lines (border bottom) from the shadow but can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions would be much appreciated

```
.tableRow { 
  border-bottom: 1px solid purple
}
.table {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border: 1px solid ${neutral30};
  border-radius: 6px;
  max-width: 1024px;

  overflow-y = auto;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff, purple, 33%, transparent),
    linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #fff, purple, 66%) 0 100%,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 0 50%, purple, transparent),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 100% 50%, purple, transparent) 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
  background-position: 0 0, 100%, 0 0, 100%;
  background-size: 30px 100%, 30px 100%, 10px 100%, 10px 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet?